# Is it possible to turn on spell-checking for only parts of buffers?

Tags: regular-expression, spell-checking

It seems that spell-checking in vim is normally enabled at a buffer level (`set spell` vs. `set nospell`). However, sometimes it would be useful to ignore certain parts of a buffer (for example, URLs in text files often contain "nonsense" from a dictionary perspective, but are nevertheless valid and correct).

Is it possible to use the spell-checking support in vim only for parts of a buffer? For example, can one define regexes to ignore? Alternatively, are there any third-party spellcheckers for vim which can do this?

Comment: AFAIK, Vim syntax files can (and often will) specify if a certain syntax region, group etc. is to be spell-checked or not. See `:h spell-syntax`. Example for LaTeX: https://github.com/gerw/vim-tex-syntax/blob/master/syntax/tex.vim#L171

Answer (score 7):

You can define syntax rule with the `@NoSpell` keyword. From [`:help :syn-spell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dspell)

```
:sy[ntax] spell [toplevel | notoplevel | default]
        This defines where spell checking is to be done for text that is not
        in a syntax item:

        toplevel:       Text is spell checked.
        notoplevel:     Text is not spell checked.
        default:        When there is a @Spell cluster no spell checking.

        For text in syntax items use the @Spell and @NoSpell clusters
        spell-syntax.  When there is no @Spell and no @NoSpell cluster then
        spell checking is done for "default" and "toplevel".

        To activate spell checking the 'spell' option must be set.
```

For example, to not spell URLs, you could use something like:

```
:syn match url /\(\s\|^\s*\*\?\)\@<=\(http\|https\|ftp\):\/\/[-0-9a-zA-Z_?&=+#%/.!':;@~]\+/ contains=@NoSpell
```

Many syntax files use this. To the best of my knowledge this is the only way to tell the Vim spell checker to ignore certain parts.

Comment: OK, thanks, I didn't know that. Does that mean (to use my example) that I'd have to modify the standard vim syntax file for text files? Or can I put this in my `.vimrc` somehow to modify an existing set of syntax rules?